# Why are the values in my dataframe columns are being changed after finishing looping over it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Here I have simple bit of code to use a "Country Code" value to map a "Country" value to each row. However in the "During" print statement I get the correct value of "United Kingdom", but in the "After" statement it is "Puerto Rico"? This method is correct for almost all values but there are ones like "Penarth" here which give random values it seems.

```
df_copy = df_filtered_coordinates.copy()
for index, row in df_filtered_coordinates.iterrows():
    map_result = country_to_code_mapping.get(row["Country Code"])
    df_copy.loc[index, "country"] = map_result
     if row["name"] == "Penarth":
         print("During", df_copy.loc[df_copy['name'] == "Penarth"])
print("After", df_copy.loc[df_copy['name'] == "Penarth"])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1KSl.png)

I tried to make a copy of the dataframe so I wasn't mutating the thing I was looping over, that didn't work. I also made sure the mapping table was correct and was returning United Kingdom. Finally I made sure that the "Penarth" row was only hit once, which it was.

Comment: Don't iterate, use `map` or `merge`